# Use ROS_ info to output std::vector data

Tags: ros, ros-info

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If I'm dealing with std::vector data in C++ and I'd like to print it on the output stream I can do something similar to what is shown below:

```
std::cout << "Data Retrieved: \n";
std::copy(data.begin(), data.end(), std::ostream_iterator<double>(std::cout, " "));
std::cout << std::endl;
```

How might I reproduce this behavior using ROS_INFO to display the data on the console as new data is received?

Thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/389585/use-ros_-info-to-output-std::vector-data/) by [rhw0023](https://answers.ros.org/users/88340/rhw0023/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2021-10-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It should be easy to use a `std::stringstream` to accomplish what you want. Moreover, it might be a bit cleaner to use `ROS_INFO_STREAM` for this particular application. Something like this:

```
  std::stringstream ss;
  ss << "Data Retrieved: \n";
  std::copy(data.begin(), data.end(), std::ostream_iterator<double>(ss, " "));
  ss << std::endl;
  ROS_INFO_STREAM(ss.str());
```

---

Originally posted by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) with karma: 9031 on 2021-10-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rhw0023](https://answers.ros.org/users/88340/rhw0023/) on 2021-10-29**:
This worked out great! Thank you!